# How do I calculate the equivalent to SQL Server (hashbytes('SHA1',[ColumnName])) in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sha

In my database I have a computed column that contains a SHA1 hash of a column called URLString which holds URLs (e.g. "http://xxxx.com/index.html").

I often need to query the table to find a specific URL based on the URLString column.
The table contains 100K's and these queries take several seconds (using SQL Azure). 
Since URLs can be quite long, I cannot create an index on this column (above 450 bytes).

To speed things up I want to calculate the equivalent of SQL Server hashbytes('SHA1',[URLString]) from C# and query based on this value.

I tried the below code, but the value I get is different than the one calculated by the database.

```
var urlString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url.URLString); //UTF8 also fails
var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(urlString);
```

Am I missing something trivial here?
I'm open to other ideas that can solve the same problem (as long as they are supported by SQL Azure).

Example: in the database the automatically calculated SHA1 value of URL http://www.whatismyip.org/ is 0xAE66CA69A157186A511ED462153D7CA65F0C1BF7.

Comment: Can you post the Insert that calculates the hash?

Comment: If your output doesn't match the server-side calculation try using one of the many online hash calculators to verify which result is correct. If one is incorrect it can be due to salt used

Comment: It's an auto-calculated column, when I insert a new URL the value is calculated and inserted by the database.

Comment: If there is a salt value, is it the same value for all SQL Servers? Can it be obtained from somewhere?

Comment: There must be a piece of SQL script somewhere that calculates it. Unless you find that there's no way of guessing what's going on

Comment: My thoughts; I might be very wrong but would a checksum not be computationally cheaper? Instead of a calculated column, which unless persisted may perform poorly, use a regular column storing the hash\checksum, index it and use it as an additional filter on your query? I know I am not answering your question, just my thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're likely getting bitten by character encoding differences:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/28/Comparing-SQL-Server-HASHBYTES-function-and-.Net-hashing.aspx

You could try getting the bytes via `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url)` or `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(url)` and see which one your db is using.

Comment: No problem - yeah, hashing algorithms are VERY sensitive to encoding.

Comment: In general you can use `Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Columns.COLLATION_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Yourtable'` to check the collation that is used for a table/column. From the collation, if it is `_CP1_` (like `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS`) then it is `Windows-1252`, if it is `_CP###_` then the ### is the codepage number (like `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CS_AS` that is 437), otherwise you have to search :-)

Comment: varchar = UTF8     / (extra accents etc) nvarchar = UNICODE

Answer (score 3):

Below are two methods that do hashing of string and of bytes. The HashBytes method returns Base64 of the resulting bytes but you can return just the bytes if you prefer them

```
public static string HashString(string cleartext)
{
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cleartext);
    return HashBytes(clearBytes);
}  

public static string HashBytes(byte[] clearBytes)
{
    SHA1 hasher = SHA1.Create();
    byte[] hashBytes =   hasher.ComputeHash(clearBytes);
    string hash = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    hasher.Clear();
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid "cleartext" and "clearbytes" terminology as this implies there's an opposite involved (e.g. "encrypted bytes" / "encrypted string"). There's no encryption going on here; only plain ol' hashing. And we all know `encryption != hashing`

Comment: this was extracted from production code and there the 'clearbytes' makes sense. It's also not a contradiction because the output is not named 'encryptedText' or 'encryptedBytes' and the input is the same 'clear text' and describe the contents appropriately

Comment: This is essentially the same solution I posted, except with SHA1.Create() instead of my new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(). I tried it and got the same result as I did before (still different that the database)

Answer (score 1):

The below code is equivalent to SQL Server's hashbytes('sha1')

```
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed()) {
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
    var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

    foreach (byte b in hash) {
        // can be "x2" if you want lowercase
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
    }

    string output = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)***

```
 DECLARE @inputString NVARCHAR(1000)
 set @inputString='Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5660  @ 2.80GHz  '
 DECLARE @outputHash VARBINARY(8000)
 SET @outputHash = HASHBYTES('SHA1', (@inputString))
 select  @outputhash
```

**returns**
0xAE325D7C3D7720846B42CDD488EBEE5D711CB1AE

***C#***

```
public string SQLServerSha1(string input) {
    SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed()
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
    var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

    foreach (byte b in hash) {
        // can be "x2" if you want lowercase
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
    }

    string output = sb.ToString();
    return output;
    }
```

**returns** AE325D7C3D7720846B42CDD488EBEE5D711CB1AE