# How to calculate hashbyte SHA1 using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hash, sql-server-2012

In a table I have a column `URL` which I am using to save urls. I am calculating the hash in another column by using formula (`CONVERT([varbinary](20),hashbytes('SHA1',[URL]))`). It's working fine.

Now I need to get similar function in C# to get hash so that I can compare and check that similar row doesnt exist before I insert a new row. I tried few links but no luck.

Here are the links:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/28/Comparing-SQL-Server-HASHBYTES-function-and-.Net-hashing.aspx

[How do I calculate the equivalent to SQL Server (hashbytes('SHA1',[ColumnName])) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146636/how-do-i-calculate-the-equivalent-to-sql-server-hashbytessha1-columnname)

```
** I found this link working. All I need to do is change formula in the db. but is it possible to make it in one line 
**
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1782626.aspx

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @BinHash varbinary(4000);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'Password@Test');
SELECT @BinHash = HashBytes('SHA1', @HashThis);

SELECT cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@BinHash")))', 'nvarchar(4000)');
```

in c#

```
string pwd = "Password@Test"; 
var sha1Provider = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1"); 
var binHash = sha1Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pwd)); 
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(binHash));
```

I am using sql server 2012. collation for the database is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Thanks

Paraminder

Comment: It would help if you would show what you are trying with C#, so we can check that code for mistakes.

Comment: Both links show how to create a hash in C#, so what is your problem?

Comment: the c# codes doesnt give me the exact hash what I have in the db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an encoding issue:

C#/.Net/CLR strings are, internally, UTF-16 encoded strings. That means each character is *at least* two bytes.

Sql Server is different:

- `char` and `varchar` represent each character as a single byte using the code page tied to the `collation` used by that column
- `nchar` and `nvarchar` represent each character as 2 bytes using the [old and obsolete] UCS-2 encoding for Unicode — something which was deprecated in 1996 with the release of Unicode 2.0 and UTF-16.

  The big difference between UTF-16 and UCS-2 is that UCS-2 can only represent characters within the Unicode BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane); UTF-16 can represent *any* Unicode character. Within the BMP, as I understand it, UCS-2 and UTF-16 representations are identical.

That means that to compute a hash that is identical to the one that SQL Server computes, you're going to have to get a byte representation that is identical to the one that SQL Server has. Since it sounds like you're using `char` or `varchar` with the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, [per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the `CP1`  part means code page 1252 and the rest means case-insensitive, accent-sensitive. So...

You can get the encoding for code page 1252 by:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Using that information, and given this table:

```
create table dbo.hash_test
(
  id          int           not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  source_text varchar(2000) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS not null ,
  hash        as
              ( hashbytes( 'SHA1' , source_text ) ) ,
)
go
insert dbo.hash_test ( source_text ) values ( 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' )
insert dbo.hash_test ( source_text ) values ( 'She looked like something that might have occured to Ibsen in one of his less frivolous moments.' )
go
```

You'll get this output

```
1: the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
   sql: 6039D100 3323D483 47DDFDB5 CE2842DF 758FAB5F
   c#:  6039D100 3323D483 47DDFDB5 CE2842DF 758FAB5F

2: She looked like something that might have occured to Ibsen in one of his less frivolous moments.
   sql: D92501ED C462E331 B0E129BF 5B4A854E 8DBC490C
   c#:  D92501ED C462E331 B0E129BF 5B4A854E 8DBC490C
```

from this program

```
class Program
{

  static byte[] Sha1Hash( string s )
  {
    SHA1    sha1         = SHA1.Create() ;
    Encoding windows1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) ;
    byte[]   octets      = windows1252.GetBytes(s) ;
    byte[]   hash        = sha1.ComputeHash( octets ) ;

    return hash ;
  }

  static string HashToString( byte[] bytes )
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < bytes.Length ; ++i )
    {
      byte b = bytes[i] ;
      if ( i > 0 && 0 == i % 4 ) sb.Append( ' ' ) ;
      sb.AppendFormat( b.ToString("X2") ) ;
    }

    string s = sb.ToString() ;
    return s ;
  }

  private static DataTable ReadDataFromSqlServer()
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( "Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    using ( SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    using ( SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) )
    {
      cmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.hash_test" ;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      conn.Open();
      sda.Fill( dt ) ;
      conn.Close() ;
    }

    return dt ;
  }

  static void Main()
  {
    DataTable dt = ReadDataFromSqlServer() ;

    foreach ( DataRow row in dt.Rows )
    {
      int    id            = (int)    row[ "id"          ] ;
      string sourceText    = (string) row[ "source_text" ] ;
      byte[] sqlServerHash = (byte[]) row[ "hash"        ] ;
      byte[] myHash        = Sha1Hash( sourceText ) ;

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine( "{0:##0}: {1}" , id , sourceText ) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "   sql: {0}" , HashToString( sqlServerHash ) ) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "   c#:  {0}" , HashToString( myHash        ) ) ;

      Debug.Assert( sqlServerHash.SequenceEqual(myHash) ) ;

    }

    return ;
  }

}
```

Easy!

Comment: Thanks man. Love it. It works great, but if the source_text field is nvarchar, it fails. any solution to that.

Comment: just changing this line made it work.   
UnicodeEncoding dstEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] octets = dstEncoding.GetBytes(s);

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hard work. I really appreciate.

Comment: @Parminder: The `Encoding` class has a static property, `Encoding.Unicode`, that provides a cached UTF-16 encoding. No need to instantiate a new one every time you need one. Ditto for the `Encoding.GetEncoding()` overloads: they provide cached copies to reduce overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that that anytime a hash is created that it be done in a single place. Either in code or on the database. It will make your life easier in the long run. That would mean either changing you C# code to create the hash before inserting the record or doing the duplication check within a stored procedure instead.

Regardless though, the duplication check and insert should be synchronized such that no other inserts could occur between the time you check for any duplicates and when the record is actually inserted. Easiest way to do that would be to perform them both within the same transaction.

If you insist on leaving the logic as it stands I would then suggest that you create the hash in the database but expose it via a stored procedure or user defined function that could be called from your C# code.