# Transact-SQL same method that C# string GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, t-sql, hashcode

How I can to get GetHashCode() in t-sql same as in C#

in c# I generate a hash from string like this:

```
"my_test_string".GetHashCode()
```

**returns =>  -958298627**

How I can use in some SELECT in SQL

Comment: HASHBYTES ( '<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )  

<algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512   but in c# is not describe witch altgorithm is used

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs line 833 and following

Comment: @Alex that's because `GetHashCode()` doesn't use a strongly defined algorithm - in fact, it has changed multiple times, and in the current version of .NET it can result in different integers for the same string in different app runs. You should never be storing a `GetHashCode()` value, or relying on specific results other than those required by the hash rules. Testing with `"my_test_string".GetHashCode()`, I get -1846333525, 
-741490224, and
-2001478594 - on successive app runs (it should always give the same answer *inside* the same app run)

Comment: What are you trying to do? I suspect a X-Y-Question.

Comment: If you need to store the hash or make sure they are the same, you should use a **specific** hash algorithm in your C# code and use the same in your SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the equivalent to SQL Server (hashbytes('SHA1',\[ColumnName\])) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146636/how-do-i-calculate-the-equivalent-to-sql-server-hashbytessha1-columnname)

Comment: @Fildor In db I have few columns that hash of concatenating string represent path directory name, I need to generate this name in SQL and not use C#

Comment: @Alex but *why* do you need to do that? Storing *just* the hash would be prone to hash collision errors; storing the hash *plus* the original composite value - would be you re-implementing how "indexes" work.

Comment: @MarcGravell that code is not my, now I need to improve that part of logic

Comment: Do I get that right: It basically is a Path where the components are stored normalized in DB? Or at least something alike?