# SHA1 Hash computes differently in SQL Server and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash, sha1

My SHA1 function in C#:

```
  unique = $"{OpDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}:{Ref}:{Type}";
            byte[] value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unique);
            using (var hash = SHA1.Create())
                unique = BitConverter.ToString(hash.ComputeHash(value)).Replace("-", "");
```

and in SQL Server my function:

```
select HASHBYTES('SHA1', (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2022-02-23',126) + Str(-1) + STR(53)))
```

when I give same inputs these functions it gives different results. How can I get same values from these two functions?

Inputs:
OpDate:022-02-23,
Ref= -1
Type=53

Result of C# : CEB17A6DB0ACE893B48DBFCE32C19D8D8EF2F661
Result of SQL : 0xC4C81724797A5E3893DD3276515EEB1FEDDC02FD

Comment: Samples would be nice.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146636/how-do-i-calculate-the-equivalent-to-sql-server-hashbytessha1-columnname/14146892#14146892) answer your question?

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging yet? It should be fairly obvious if you compare the outputs of `Console.WriteLine(unique);` and `select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2022-02-23',126) + Str(-1) + STR(53)` that the plaintext values are substantially different.

Comment: ^^ `How can I get same values from these two functions?` => Use the same inputs.  Also read the docs on [STR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It's not doing what you think it is